# Avoid multiple execution of a role for server in more groups?

Tags: ansible

I have **six** server groups, but for the example, let's say I have **two** groups: `dbserver` and `webserver`. My inventory looks like:

```
[dbserver]
db.com
both.com
[webserver]
web.com
both.com
```

My playbooks looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: dbserver
  roles:
    - { role: commonrole }
    - { role: dbrole }
- hosts: webserver
  roles:
    - { role: commonrole }
    - { role: webrole }
```

However, when I run the playbook for server `both.com`, the `commonrole` gets executed twice!

In this simple example I could of course put the `commonrole` in a common group:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - { role: commonrole }
```

or create a

```
- hosts: db_and_web_server
  roles:
    - { role: commonrole }
    - { role: dbrole }
    - { role: webrole }
```

but for **six** groups I would end up with up to 63 combinations of groups.

I would like ansible to gather all roles needed for a specific machine, remove duplicates and *then* execute the roles.

Or can I change the design of my playbook?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_fact` action in your common role.
Facts for hosts are cached for every play in the playbook.
For example, your common role main.yaml might look like:

```
---
- include: common.yml
  when: common_has_run is not defined

- set_fact: common_has_run=true
  when: common_has_run is not defined
```

Where common.yml contains all tasks for common role.
This trick was found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/nd4wMLsb0Jw).